# query to modify the constraint in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query from oracle query point of view is that I have created a constraint on table BOA_INVOICE as shown below

```
ALTER TABLE BOA_INVOICE ADD CONSTRAINT CK_INVOICE_SOURCE_SYSTEM CHECK ( SOURCE_SYSTEM IN ('PCE','PDS'));
```

Now this constraint is added successfully , but later on i want to modify same constraint add two values as shown below

```
 ALTER TABLE BOA_INVOICE ADD CONSTRAINT CK_INVOICE_SOURCE_SYSTEM CHECK ( SOURCE_SYSTEM IN ('PCE','PDS','PER','AWE'));
```

Please advise what will be the query to achieve the same

Comment: Hi there. Please, if the given answer solves your problem consider in accepting it. Just click on the V icon on the left on the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to drop the constraint first and then create it again.

```
 ALTER TABLE BOA_INVOICE  DROP CONSTRAINT CK_INVOICE_SOURCE_SYSTEM;
```

Then Create it again:

```
 ALTER TABLE BOA_INVOICE ADD CONSTRAINT 
      CK_INVOICE_SOURCE_SYSTEM CHECK ( SOURCE_SYSTEM IN ('PCE','PDS','PER','AWE'));
```